# SQL Select all rows containing status except rows that have a corresponding row with different status

Tags: sql, db2

I'm on Db2 for IBM I. Except this might also apply to SQL Server.

Here's an example of what the data looks like in my HISTRY table...

| ID | TICKETNUM | DATEREVIEWED | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ab123456 | 10/20/2022 | HM |
| 124 | ab123456 | 10/21/2022 | AM |
| 125 | ab456123 | 10/19/2022 | HM |
| 126 | ab789123 | 10/15/2022 | AM |
| 127 | ab891234 | 10/13/2022 | HM |

I want to select all rows with STATUS = HM, but not if a row has a corresponding row with STATUS = AM, which TICKETNUM ab123456 has.  I tried using WHERE NOT IN (..) but that doesn't address the problem. My other thought was that I might have to use a temp table which I'm just slightly leery of because of the cleanup involved afterward.

Currently, in order to get what I want, I'm using C# code where I'm creating two List with one list containing all HM statuses and the other containing all AM, then For-Each looping with a sub For-Each removing any AMs from the HM's list. Brutish but it works. Now am backtracking because I would prefer the logic for this special needs SELECT to be handled all by SQL in a stored procedure.

Any input and extra brain muscle and elbow grease would be much appreciated. **TIA!**

Comment: *but that doesn't address the problem* - why not? Show us your query.

Comment: @Stu  Here you go...  SELECT 
  H . "ID" ,
  H . "TICKETNUM" ,
  H . "DATEREVIEWED" ,
  H . "STATUS"
 FROM MYTABLE . "HISTRY" AS H
 WHERE H . "STATUS" NOT IN ('AG','DM','MH','RC','RM') 
 ORDER BY H . "TICKETNUM" ASC ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would use a left join or the `NOT EXISTS` operator.

A solution with the latter can look like:

```
select *
from HISTRY a
where status = 'HM'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from HISTRY b 
    where b.ticketnum = a.ticketnum and b.status = 'AM'
  )
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! This worked! I actually remember going the route of a not exists with sub-select but it didn't work because my where clause only had as in your example the b.status = 'AM'. Didn't think to also include a match criteria  b.ticketnum = a.ticketnum.